# why does my sphere go up in Unity if in the script I only want to rotate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a moving ground and a sphere where I only want to rotate. The problem is that ball go up sometimes and it lose the position.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    AnimacionBola();
}

void AnimacionBola()
{
    transform.Rotate(EstadoJuego.velocidadSuelo * angleOfRotation * Vector3.right, Space.World);
}
```

Why is it happen?

Comment: I don't see why it should in your code ... Are you sure the pivot point of your objects is where you expect it to be (center of the geometry)? Could you add some screenshot/video of the issue .. it is a bit hard to understand what exactly you mean

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can happen depending on the situation, some of them are:

1. the local origin of your sphere is not at the center of the geometry.
2. One more thing can happen that you have made the sphere child of another object whose center doesn't match with the sphere's center.

If that is the case, then you should go through the transform API of unity or you can watch this playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrtqd9jHm30NpiIOF7-SkYUmOW0D0gQh8